# Can't Convert A Float in Array to String

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a sine, cosine, tangent, and cotangent table. I want to `printf`/`cout` an `"INF"` instead of huge complicated numbers or interesting symbols when I calculate the cotangent of 0. But it doesn't allow me to do this. I tried every way I can think of, but I couldn't do it.

Can you help me about that?

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.14159265
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");

    string diziBaslik[1][5] = {{"AÇI","SİN","COS","TAN","COTAN"}};
    string diziBaslikCizgi[1][5] = {{"------","------","------","------","------"}};
    float dizi[10][5] = {
        {0 ,sin(0*PI/180) ,cos(0*PI/180) ,tan(0*PI/180) ,1/tan(0*PI/180) },
        {10,sin(10*PI/180),cos(10*PI/180),tan(10*PI/180),1/tan(10*PI/180)},
        {20,sin(20*PI/180),cos(20*PI/180),tan(20*PI/180),1/tan(20*PI/180)},
        {30,sin(30*PI/180),cos(30*PI/180),tan(30*PI/180),1/tan(30*PI/180)},
        {40,sin(40*PI/180),cos(40*PI/180),tan(40*PI/180),1/tan(40*PI/180)},
        {50,sin(50*PI/180),cos(50*PI/180),tan(50*PI/180),1/tan(50*PI/180)},
        {60,sin(60*PI/180),cos(60*PI/180),tan(60*PI/180),1/tan(60*PI/180)},
        {70,sin(70*PI/180),cos(70*PI/180),tan(70*PI/180),1/tan(70*PI/180)},
        {80,sin(80*PI/180),cos(80*PI/180),tan(80*PI/180),1/tan(80*PI/180)},
        {90,sin(90*PI/180),cos(90*PI/180),tan(90*PI/180),1/tan(90*PI/180)}
    };
    
    cout << diziBaslik[0][0] << "\t";
    
    for(int j=1;j<5;j++){
        cout << diziBaslik[0][j] << "\t\t";
    }
    
    cout<< endl;
    
    cout << diziBaslikCizgi[0][0] << "\t";
    
    for(int j=1;j<5;j++){
        cout << diziBaslikCizgi[0][j] << "\t\t";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(j==0){
                cout << dizi[i][j] << "\xB0\t";
            }
            else{
                printf("%.6f\t", dizi[i][j]);
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `cout` and `printf` show `inf` given `float x = 1/tan(0*PI/180); cout << x;`

Comment: Just replace `1/tan(0*PI/180)` and `tan(90*PI/180)` with `INFINITY`. `cout` will print `inf`.

Comment: I think that your problem goes more with `tan(90*PI/180)` than with `cotan(0)` because your program already shows `inf` for `cotan(0)`. The problem is with `tan(90*PI/180)`because you can't give enough precission to PI so that the tangent of that angle reaches infinity. I would go with the comment by rustyx, it's probably your best option.

Comment: Sidenote: You can do `std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed;` if you want to use `std::cout` instead of `std::printf("%.6f", ...)`.

Comment: @rustyx thanks for advice. I did it. Now it says "1,#INF00". Can I change it by "INFINITY" or any letter else?

Comment: @Brian sorry, I'm new in the platform.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It gives me an error like "setprecision is not a member of std"

Comment: @Abdurrahman2234 `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hello again, When I change "printf("%.6f\t", dizi[i][j]);" as "std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << dizi[i][j] << "\t";", the order of the application is broken. Array columns do not line up. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Abdurrahman2234 [Looks the same](https://godbolt.org/z/EqTvYzo5a)  for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. Due to low PI precision, `tan(90*PI/180)` returns a large number and not infinity.
2. Your system is printing infinity as `1,#INF00`. I don't think there's a way to change that.

To work around both issues don't let large values go to `printf` and instead print your own string if the value is larger than some tolerance value:

```
        if (dizi[i][j] < 1e5) {
            printf("%.6f\t", dizi[i][j]);
        } else {
            printf("INFINITY\t");
        }
```

---

Also note that `setlocale()` won't affect `cout` because it's constructed before. For `cout` you need to add something like

```
  cout.imbue(std::locale("Turkish"));
```